# You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate

Tags: flutter, google-play-services

I signed my app with a new key by mistake cause I had two windows open at the same time and I get this message"You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate." when I try to update my app now, is there a way of updating my app and fixing the problem?

Comment: AFAIK, you only able to update your app using the same certificate. So.. upload again that signed with the same certificate is your best bet. Unless your certificate is lost somewhere

Comment: Rebuild your app and sign it with the original certificate you used.